# Is there any recommended number of files/Images to be stored within Android project?

Tags: android

What is the correct way to store files within Android Project? 
All files in local folders? All in webserver? 50/50 ?

The reason I am asking is because my project's size has been increasing a lot due to the number of drawables and I am afraid I should do something about it. 
Can this compromise the app performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The large app size i.e. apk file size might not compromise your app performance but, will certainly make it slower to install your app. From the user's perspective, if two apps provide same features and have similar performance the size of their apk files will be the deciding factor for them to install your app.

Using web server to save drawables can be an efficient way if your app is a web based app. In case, your app does not require web access or internet access for any other purpose, don't save drawables on the web server.

However, I would suggest you to reduce the size of your drawable files in such a way that their quality is not effected. All this can be achieved by help of tools like Photoshop (I have personally not tried this but know that it is possible).

You can also use nine-patch drawables. These drawable files can stretch themselves along the sides specified without compromising the image's quality. For more info on the same visit following links:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html

Also, make sure that your icons are of specifications as specified in the Material Design Guidelines. Visit the link for more details: https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#